# how to match the bracket and inside letters

Tags: javascript, regex

If I have a string like this,

```
aaa[cid:image.jpg]aaa[uu]
```

how can I get `[cid:image.jpg]` only?

currently, I can get both `[cid:image.jpg]` and `[uu]` with the following pattern:

```
\[[^\]]*\]
```

But I'd like to add image.jpg as a condition?

Comment: How about `\[cid:[^\]]*\]` ?

Answer (score 1):

If the string matches the pattern `[cid:????]`, you can try using the regex in this form: `\[cid:[^\]]*\]`

Answer (score 1):

How about that:

```js
var str = "aaa[cid:image.jpg]aaa[uu]";

// Original
console.log(str.match(/\[[^\]]*\]/g));

// Matching 'cid:' prefix
console.log(str.match(/\[cid:[^\]]*\]/g));

// Matching 'image.jpg' sufix
console.log(str.match(/\[[^\]]*\image.jpg]/g));
```

Comment: Thanks for editing my answer and giving out the right answer.

Comment: @Suwen no problem! I'm glad to help. You have to check as answer the answer which helped you, don't forget it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex :

```
\[cid:.+\.jpg\]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: yes, this code does answer my question. Thanks @Simo. As Badacadabra mentioned, I just wanna to replace[cid:image.jpg] with<img> tag, in order to display the image directly with the words. This comes from email preview.